# How to verify if prop passed is a Component type in Svelte?

Tags: svelte, svelte-3, svelte-component

I am having a prop which takes either a `function` or `Component`. So I want to differentiate by checking types of prop whether it's a component or function. I am at present using following one. This may not work in prod when code gets obfuscated. Wanted to know better solution?

```
let isSvelteComponent = component => {
    return (
      typeof component !== "undefined" &&
      component.__proto__.name === "SvelteComponentDev"
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 3):

I would argue that, loosely speaking, any function can potentially be a valid Svelte component:

```html
<script>
    import B from './B.svelte'

    const C = function(opts) {
        return new B(opts)
    }
</script>

<B />   

<C />
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/86e09fff93a24459a33b7a410f5a8446?version=3.16.7)

As such, there isn't really a completely reliable way to tell appart a Svelte component from a regular function.

In your case, if the Svelte component and the function have different meaning and should be handled differently, maybe they should be passed through different props? That would allow to know for sure what is what, and what it is intended for.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by checking prototype like following

```js
import { SvelteComponent } from "svelte";
let isSvelteComponent = component => {
   return SvelteComponent.isPrototypeOf(component);
};
```

Comment: Seems to be working! Have you encountered edge cases where this test might fail? For the record, I use `return Object.prototype.isPrototypeOf.call(SvelteComponent, component);`, as per my ESLint recommendations!

Comment: For the record, this kind of check is lost through code minification. To this day, I don't have a reliable way to differentiate a Svelte component.

Comment: @DSav that thing about code minification is scary. could you explay why that happens?

Comment: @Paolo I'm not sure if "code minification" is actually what is going on, to be honest. I didn't dig much into this since this reply. However, from what I remember, there was a difference that made this trick work in development, but not in production (I think I was using this in a Meteor project).

Please don't take my word for it and try it out yourself. I'm a more experienced programmer now and maybe I would find out why it didn't work out then, but I don't use this trick anymore, I'm sorting my components differently.